# Using the for..in loop to access JSON data

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm just learning how to retrieve data from a JSON file and put it to good use, and I've found the for..in loop helpful, but I know I'm doing too much to get a value out of a JSON file.

This is my JSON - it does't have to be structured this way.

```
var dollars = { "zipcodes": {
    "one": {
      "donors": {
          "donor_profile1": {
                   "name": "Doug Smith",
                   "address" : "123 main st",
                   "gifts":{
                    "gift0": {
                         "recipient":"Greg",
                         "amount": 45000,
                         "date":"7/1/2013"
                         },
                     "gift1":{
                        "recipient":"Greg",
                        "amount": 6000,
                        "date":"7/1/2013"
                        },
                        "gift2":{
                        "recipient":"Marty",
                        "amount": 2000,
                        "date":"7/1/2013"
                        }
                    }
                   },
            "donor_profile2": {
                        "name": "Bert Bernard",
                        "address" : "123 South st",
                        "gifts": {
                            "gift0": {
                            "recipient":"Greg",
                            "amount": 1200,
                            "date":"7/4/2013"
                              },
                            "gift1":{
                            "recipient":"Marty",
                            "amount": 400,
                            "date":"7/9/2013"
                            },
                            "gift2":{
                            "recipient":"Marty",
                            "amount": 510,
                            "date":"7/21/2013"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to gather all the gifts given by each donor and add them up. I've written this program to get ALL the gift amounts, but they aren't separated by donor. Any advice on how to make this cleaner?

```
var info = dollars.zipcodes.one;


function buildSum(){
for (var key in info){

if (info.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var person = info[key];
    };
    for (prop in person) {
        if(person.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            var name = person[prop].gifts;
        };
            for(value in name){
                if(name.hasOwnProperty(value)){
                    var money = name[value].amount;

                    };
                }

            }                       
    }

}
buildSum();
```

Comment: It's been a bit since I've done JSON, but aren't you able to put in a collection inside an object? Like "gifts":[{"date: today", "amount":"4500"},{"date":"yesterday", "amount":"5600"}]?

Comment: @CBredlow Yeah, he should definitely be using an array somewhere in here.

Comment: That's *not* JSON.  JSON is a *string representation* of data, that just so happens to resemble JavaScript syntax.  Your `var dollars` is not a string, therefore it's not JSON.  It's a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: I think you want `for(key in info.donors)` and `if (info.donors.hasOwnProperty(key)){ var person = info.donors[key]; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if (info.hasOwnProperty(key))
> ```

You don't need that check. Your values are plain objects, and nobody is silly enough to extend `Object.prototype` with enumerable properties.

> ```
> for (prop in person)
> ```

That seems unncessary, if not wrong. You just want to access the `gifts` property, so there's no need to enumerate over `name`, `address` and `gifts`. Same thing with

> ```
> for (var key in info)
> ```

where you just want to get the `donors` and iterate over them - the object doesn't even have any other properties.

> my JSON does't have to be structured this way

Then I would recommend to use arrays for the `gifts` and `donors` collections, unless those `gift0`, `gift1` etc. are necessary ids for items.

```
var dollars = {
    "zipcodes": {
        "one": {
            "donors": [
                 {
                    "name": "Doug Smith",
                    "address": "123 main st",
                    "gifts": [
                        {
                            "recipient": "Greg",
                            "amount": 45000,
                            "date": "7/1/2013"
                        },
                        {
                            "recipient": "Greg",
                            "amount": 6000,
                            "date": "7/1/2013"
                        },
                        {
                            "recipient": "Marty",
                            "amount": 2000,
                            "date": "7/1/2013"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Bert Bernard",
                    "address": "123 South st",
                    "gifts": [
                        {
                            "recipient": "Greg",
                            "amount": 1200,
                            "date": "7/4/2013"
                        },
                        {
                            "recipient": "Marty",
                            "amount": 400,
                            "date": "7/9/2013"
                        },
                        {
                            "recipient": "Marty",
                            "amount": 510,
                            "date": "7/21/2013"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

```
var donors = dollars.zipcodes.one.donors;
sum = 0;
for (var i=0; i<donors.length; i++) {
    var donor = donors[i],
        gifts = donor.gifts;
    var money = 0;
    for (var j=0; j<gifts.length; j++) {
        money += gifts[j].amount;
    }
    console.log(donor.name+" spent "+money);
    sum += money;
}
console.log("alltogether they spent "+sum);
```

> Any advice on how to make this cleaner?

You could use [`Array::reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for a more functional approach:

```
var sum = dollars.zipcodes.one.donors.reduce(function(s, donor) {
    var money = donor.gifts.reduce(function(m, gift) {
        return m+gift.amount;
    }, 0);
    console.log(donor.name+" spent "+money);
    return s+money;
}, 0);
```

Comment: `zipcodes` is still badly wanting to be an array, if the `one` is not a fake index, then that should be a property of a zipcode object.

Comment: @Esailija: You could be right, yes. I hadn't expected that as the OP was directly accessing `var info = dollars.zipcodes.one;` and not attempting to iterate it.

Comment: Yeah, I will be iterating over that. There will be multiple zip codes, so That should be an array then?

Comment: Yup, it might be. However, zip codes are pretty good ids and hardly have an order, so an object is fine imho. Choose yourself whether `regions: [ {zipcode: "12345", donors: […]}, …]` or `zipcodes: { "12345": {donors:[…]}, … }` fits better.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment section, you probably should use an array where it is appropriate.  So your JSON data could look like this:

```
var dollars = {
    "zipcodes": {
        "one": {
            "donors": [{
                "name": "Doug Smith",
                    "address": "123 main st",
                    "gifts": [{
                    "recipient": "Greg",
                        "amount": 45000,
                        "date": "7/1/2013"
                }, {
                    "recipient": "Greg",
                        "amount": 6000,
                        "date": "7/1/2013"
                }, {
                    "recipient": "Marty",
                        "amount": 2000,
                        "date": "7/1/2013"
                }]
            }, {
                "name": "Bert Bernard",
                    "address": "123 South st",
                    "gifts": [{
                    "recipient": "Greg",
                        "amount": 1200,
                        "date": "7/4/2013"
                }, {
                    "recipient": "Marty",
                        "amount": 400,
                        "date": "7/9/2013"
                }, {
                    "recipient": "Marty",
                        "amount": 510,
                        "date": "7/21/2013"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

This enables you to use some functions of `Array.prototype`. In my case I use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), to produce an array with the total amount of donated money by each donor:

```
//first map: turn the array of donors in an array of gift array
var res = dollars.zipcodes.one.donors.map(function (item) {

    //second map: turn each gift array in an array of amount
    return item.gifts.map(function (item) {
        return item.amount;

    //use reduce to sum up the amount in each array
    }).reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
});

console.log(res); //[53000, 2110]
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6vUEh/)**